# Why does the full contraction of a tensor and its (Hodge) dual is a pseudoscalar?

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus

I'm trying to prove that the contraction between a tensor and its dual is a pseudoscalar, while the contraction of the dual with itself is just a scalar. I'm using index notation and every time I try to demonstrate it I seem to show the opposite. Any tip on how to proceed ?

The calculation is: $$(\epsilon^{\mu \nu \alpha \beta}F_{\alpha \beta}F_{\mu \nu})^{\prime} = det(\Lambda)(\epsilon^{\mu \nu \alpha \beta}F_{\alpha \beta}F_{\mu \nu})$$

Where: $\Lambda$ is the lorentz transformation matrix and $\epsilon^{\mu \nu \alpha \beta}$ is the Levi-Civita pseudotensor.

Comment: Aren't you already done? The determinant is there for a pseudoscalar but not a scalar.

Comment: Yes but if I start from the left side and actually expand it and calculate it I can't get to the right side, that is my problem.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
ε^{αβγδ}{F'}_{αβ}{F'}_{γδ}
&= ε^{αβγδ}\left(Λ^μ_αΛ^ν_βF_{μν}\right)\left(Λ^ρ_γΛ^σ_δF_{ρσ}\right) \\
&= \left(ε^{αβγδ}Λ^μ_αΛ^ν_βΛ^ρ_γΛ^σ_δ\right)F_{μν}F_{ρσ} \\
&= \left(\det{Λ}ε^{μνρσ}\right)F_{μν}F_{ρσ} \\
&= \det{Λ}\left(ε^{μνρσ}F_{μν}F_{ρσ}\right).
\end{align}$$

Comment: The mistake I was making is that I was also transforming $\epsilon$. Why don't you transform it ? Isn't it also a tensor ?

Comment: Actually, it's the epitome of a pseudo-tensor. It's the inverse of $ε_{μνρσ}$ which is the component form of the tensor $\frac{1}{4!} ε_{μνρσ} dx^μ dx^ν dx^ρ dx^σ$, i.e. the $4$-form $d^4x ≡ dx^0 ∧ dx^1 ∧ dx^2 ∧ dx^3$. And what's
the transform rule for that? Jacobian! $d^4(Λx) = \det{Λ} d^4x$. To "tensorize" it, you need a metric $g_{μν} dx^μ dx^ν$. Then $η_{μνρσ} ≡ \sqrt{|g|} ε_{μνρσ}$ is
a tensor. That's the tensorized volume form $\sqrt{|g|} d^4x$. So, for $ε^{μνρσ}$, I think you need to divide: $η^{μνρσ} ≡ ε^{μνρσ}/\sqrt{|g|}$. $ε_{μνρσ}$ and $ε^{μνρσ}$ are densities of weight +1 and -1.

Comment: Thank you very much!